# React Redux not able to insert an object into nested array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im trying to insert object into particular object(i.e list of object ). Below is the code.

```
import MESSAGES from '../actions/Messages';
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const chatReducer = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case CHATS:
            // state = [...state, payload];
            // return state;
            return state, payload;
        case MESSAGES:
            let index = state.findIndex(
                chat =>  chat.chatId === payload.chatId);
            const conn = state[index];
            const messages = [...conn.messages, payload];
            const newState = state.slice();
            newState[index] = { ...conn, messages };
            //console.log("ne ", newState)
            return newState;
        default:
            return state
    };
};

export default chatReducer;
```

Here am just finding the object based on the id and inserting the payload into messages array which is not working.

Comment: when state is empty array, your `index` would be undefined

Comment: also `return state, payload;` seems not correct.

Comment: @SaeedShamloo yes the state is an array of object values are there. i just did a debug.

Comment: what is the output of  `console.log("ne ", newState)`? is it your expected result?

Comment: no its not printed.

Comment: did you uncommented it?

Comment: yes. debugged it shows undefined.

Comment: its a combination with state array and inserting payload into it (i.e updated array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question thanks @Rahul Sharma you just redirected me. i changed the object because of my app requirements.

```
import CHATS from '../actions/ChatMessages';
import MESSAGES from '../actions/Messages';
import SEARCH from '../actions/SearchUser';

const chatReducer = (state = {}, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case CHATS:
            return { ...state, payload };
        case MESSAGES:
            let index = state.payload.chats.findIndex(
                chat => chat.chatId === payload.chatId
            );
            let conn = state.payload.chats[index];
            const msg = payload.msg;
            conn.lastMsg = msg;
            const messages = [...conn.messages, payload];
            const newState = { ...state };
            newState.payload.chats[index] = { ...conn, messages };
            console.log("state ", newState);
            return newState;
        default:
            return state
    };
};

export default chatReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of 2 checks

1. If index -1 (chat id does not found): Add new chat object
2. don't do slice it'll only return the rest of the items and the index will mismatch

```
    const chatReducer = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
      switch (type) {
        case CHATS:
          // state = [...state, payload];
          // return state;
          return [...state, ...payload];
        case MESSAGES:
          let index = state.findIndex((chat) => chat.chatId === payload.chatId);
    
          if (index !== -1) {
            const conn = state[index];
            const messages = [...conn.messages, payload];
            const newState = [...state]; // use destructuring instead of slice
            newState[index] = { ...conn, messages };
            return newState;
          }
          return [
            ...state,
            /* <add new chat object> */
          ]; // Do something if the chat doesn't exist
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: @RED are you getting any error

Comment: While debugging its shows undefined. but i have state array and payload. Since nothing is printed in console.

Comment: @RED is this typo `return state, payload;`

Comment: im just returning the state array and adding payload into it. is it wrong to `return state, payload;` ?

Comment: it should be `return[...state, payload]` , I've update my answer also

Comment: No luck @Rahul Sharma.

Comment: ```{
  type: {
    type: 'CHATS',
    payload: []
  },
  payload: [
    {
      chatId: '61cc5ec57aa50c1f779fd2fe',
      members: [
        'dref6977',
        'ddee7901'
      ],
      createdDate: 1640783556663,
      lastMsg: 'hi',
      chatName: '[dref6977, ddee7901]',
      messages: [],
      uptDate: 1641035176727
    }
  ]
}```
Any problem on this ? I'm seeing this in redux.

Comment: @RED use `return [...state, ...payload];`